# A contradiction caused by the Kähler identity and the formal adjoint relation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

I found a contradiction in the *Principle of Algebraic Geometry* by G&H, section 1.2. I have post this on MSE but it didn't get enough attention. I couldn't sleep or eat or do anything else due to this contradiction. Orz.

Assume $\eta$ is a harmonic form, $L$ is multiplying by Kähler and $\Lambda$ its adjoint. Then we have
$$(L\Lambda \eta , \eta) = (\Lambda \eta , \Lambda \eta) \ge 0.$$
But as in the *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris, p. 154, in the proof of the Kodaira Vanishing, we have
$$
(L \Lambda \eta , \eta) = i/2\pi (\Theta \Lambda \eta , \eta) = i/2\pi (D' \bar{\partial} \Lambda \eta ,\eta)
$$
since $\Theta = D'D'' + D''D'$, $\bar{\partial} = D''$,  $(\bar{\partial} x , \eta) = (x, \bar{\partial}^* \eta)$ and $\bar{\partial}^*\eta = 0$ since $\eta$ is a harmonic form. By the famous identity $[ \Lambda , \bar{\partial}] = -iD'^*$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
i/2\pi (D' \bar{\partial} \Lambda \eta ,\eta) & = i/2\pi (D' (\Lambda \bar{\partial}+iD'^*)  \eta ,\eta) \\
& = -1/2\pi (D'D'^* \eta ,\eta) \\
& =- 1/2\pi (D'^* \eta , D'^* \eta) \le 0.
\end{split}
$$

We get two inequality of different directions. It would implies $\Lambda \eta = 0$. What's wrong here?

Comment: I do not have the book with me right now, so I cannot check. Anyway: are you sure that this is a scalar product and not a *hermitian* one?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi This is a Hermitian one . Does it matter?

Comment: Well, so how can you conclude that positivity holds in the first inequality? It seems to me that you need the conjugate in the second argument, or I am missing something?

Comment: I mean, for a hermitian product we have $\langle z, \, \bar{z} \rangle \geq 0$, not $\langle z, \, z \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi In this book, the parenthesis product $(a,b)$ means $<a, \bar{b}>$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi You may download the book from your institute's library.

Comment: With no disrespect to  G or H, their book is known to have many mistakes. So I wouldn't lose sleep over it. I suppose that there must be a sign inconsistency in the parts you were reading.

Comment: @DonuArapura It is not only about G&H. The nightmare is when I refer to the Demailly's note, I get the same conclusion.

Comment: @DonuArapura As long as you recognize those several famous Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano Identity, or even more the elementary Kahler identities and the definition of adjoint, you will get this contradiction. Though stupid, it makes me feel that mathematicians have done wrong in almost a century.

Comment: You have to be REALLY careful about conjugation, the powers of $i$ and signs of terms. I suggest you write everything out with the real and imaginary terms shown explicitly. If you do this a few times, you’ll learn how to use the briefer notation correctly or at least become better at checking your calculations. Unfortunately, as @DonuArapura said, this book is infamous for errors like this.

Comment: @DeaneYang If you don't believe in G&H, you should (maybe) believe in Demailly. This identity is the same as the one from the Demailly's note. The first equality in this post is just the definition of adjoint, without any possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a explanation. Noting that in this question $\eta$ is a harmonic form in $\Omega^{p,q}(L)$ where $L$ is a positive line bundle. And harmony means $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} \eta =0$.

First of all, we find that $[\Delta , L] = i(\bar{\partial} D' + D' \bar{\partial})$ which is not necessary zero, which is how everything behaves in $\Omega(L)$, unlike in $\Omega$. This means though $\eta$ is harmonic in $\Omega(L)$, $L\eta$ is not necessary harmonic. So there is no way to conclude $L \eta = 0$ for all harmonic $\eta$ from the fact $\Lambda \eta = 0$ for all harmonic $\eta$. So things is not absurd enough. Though $\Lambda \eta = 0$ is already very astonishing.